# How to async load vuetify dropdown(v-select) items in Vue

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have an issue to asynchronously fetch data for the [`v-select`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) Vuetify Component. The thing is the `v-select` component does only except `Array`for the `:items` attribute. What is the workaround to fetch data asynchronously :

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got
>   Promise

**template**:

```
<template>
    <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 md6 v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index" v-show="!field.hidden">
            <v-text-field v-if="field.component === 'v-text-field'" :label="field.label"></v-text-field>
            <v-select
                v-else-if="field.component === 'v-select' "
                :label="field.label"
                :items="(typeof field.items === 'string') ? getLookups(field.items) : []"
            ></v-select>
            <v-checkbox v-else-if="field.component === 'v-checkbox'" :label="field.label"></v-checkbox>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>
```

**async method**:

```
async getLookups( api: string | string[]) {
    // Mock Async timeout
    var wait = (ms: any) => new Promise((r, j) => setTimeout(r, ms));
    wait(2000);
    return ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
}
```

Comment: > `The thing is the v-select component does only except Array for the :items attribute.`  - What do you mean "the thing"? What's wrong with it? Just pass the array.

Comment: Yes I know it accepts array. The problem was that the array is not ready at runtime, but fetched asynchronously. It would have been nice if it accepted async promise type. But got a work around if you look at the answer.

Comment: Yes, and in the answer it seems you set `lookups` as an object (so your question is not clear actually without looking at the answer). But I still don't understand why don't you set it as array (i.e. `lookups = []`), and then in your fetch `this.lookups = data`? Thus you always pass array, and also there is `loading` prop which could be true for example when array is empty (if you expect results always) or you you could set additional loading data.

Comment: Because it's a dynamic form builder. There could be multiple dropdowns or just 1. That's why lookups is a object because it could contain the lookups of multiple dropdowns in the form. I will create a runnable example.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution/workaround I found is creating a local variable and return the local variable instance. I just pass through the index to create a unique object for my dynamic component

**template**:

```
<template>
    <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 md6 v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index" v-show="!field.hidden">
            <v-text-field v-if="field.component === 'v-text-field'" :label="field.label"></v-text-field>
            <v-select
                v-else-if="field.component === 'v-select' "
                :label="field.label"
                :items="(typeof field.items === 'string') ? getLookups(index, field.items) : field.items"
            ></v-select>
            <v-checkbox v-else-if="field.component === 'v-checkbox'" :label="field.label"></v-checkbox>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>
```

**script**:

```
private lookups: any = {};

getLookups(index: number, api: string | string[]) {
    // Mock Async timeout
    var wait = (ms: any) => new Promise((r, j) => setTimeout(r, ms));
    wait(2000).then(() => {
        this.lookups[index] = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
    });
    return this.lookups[index];
}
```

So the `v-select` component will be listening to the local variable. As soon as it populated it would update the `v-select` items.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative could be using `asyncComputed`, it's an [opensource project](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed).

```
data: {
    userId: 1
},
asyncComputed: {
 async getLookups( api: string | string[]) {
   // Mock Async timeout
  var wait = (ms: any) => new Promise((r, j) => setTimeout(r, ms));
  wait(2000);
  return ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thx @Ruslan, asyncComputed works great. Below is an extract from my code "GetClients" is the computed source for my select.

```js
async created() {
    if (this.id) {
      this.action = "Update";
      this.getItem();
    }
  },
  asyncComputed:{
    async getClients(){
      const items = await API.graphql({
        query: listClients
      });
      return items.data.listClients.items;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getItem() {
```